# performance issue for spring r2dbc

Tags: performance, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

Problem : slowness observed during first 1 sec only and the remaining 59 have a constant response time which 90% better than the max response time.

Server Env details: spring boot webflux with r2dbc pool deployed in ECS fargate and connecting to Postgres Aurora cluster.
pool settings - maxSize,initialSize is 200
Using spring data r2dbc and enabled proxy listener for debugging.

Client  :
A gatling script with a very minimal load of 200,250,300,500 users with a ramp time of 50 sec is configured in AWS EC2 in same VPC.

Scenario

1. ECS server started.
2. wait for 4 min.
3. did a dry run of 5 requests using postman.
4. trigger load using gatling
5. Shutdown the ECS.
6. repeat the steps with a different number of users.

*The behaviour is consistent with different users. Always the first 1 min has the slowest responses and having the max response time.*
Subsequent runs without server restart has a good performance without any delays.

Total|OK  |KO|Cnt/s|Min|50th pct|75th pct|95th pct|99th pct|Max   |Mean |Std Dev|

500  |500 |0 |9.804|94 |184     |397     |1785    |2652    | 2912 | 417 | 556   |

And also observed in the logs the time difference between these two immediate lines logged is 168ms for the request with max response time.
-- Executing query: BEGIN
-- io.r2dbc.spi.Connection.beginTransaction callback at ConnectionFactory#create()

Any suggestion how to approach/fix the issue?

Thanks.